# jQuery textbox hinter plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a page with a textbox defined like...

```
<input type="text" hinttext="Here is the hint text" />
```

I am trying to set the 'hint' text of the control using the tbHinter call and have tried...

```
$('input').tbHinter({ text: this.getAttribute('hinttext') });
```

and

```
$('input').tbHinter({ text:this.attr('hinttext') });
```

neither work.

I know I am missing something obvious.  Can someone point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your initial example `this` most likely is going to be a reference to the `window`.  To accomplish this you will need to iterate over each input box so you have a reference to the input.

```
$('input').each(function(){
  $(this).tbHinter({ text: $(this).attr('hinttext') });
});
```

Example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/jpDB5/).

Comment: Perfect, thanks so much.  I had tried a version of the each, but mine used 'this' instead of the jQuery $(this).  'this' just returns the elements, so there is no tbHinter method for that.  Makes sense, thanks.